# ScrollMagic cancels pseudo-selectors

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, libraries, scrollmagic

I'm trying to use ScrollMagic library to use "Section Wipes" effect and i apply a color for every second div, using **nth-child(even)** but it doesn't seem to work with ScrollMagic. All boxes become white
Html:

```
    <div class="box" data="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box" data="box-2"></div>
    <div class="box" data="box-3"></div>
    <div class="box" data="box-4"></div>
    <div class="box" data="box-5"></div>
```

Css:

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;   
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Javascript:

```
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');



let controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
    globalSceneOptions: {
        triggerHook: 'onLeave',
    }
});


for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: boxes[i]
    })
    .setPin(boxes[i], )
    .addTo(controller);
}
```

Comment: `.box:nth-child(even)` won't work because `.box` elements are not siblings anymore, they get wrapped by .`scrollmagic-pin-spacer`

Comment: Oh my god. That was so simple and I didn't get it....Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.box:nth-child(even)` won't work because `.box` elements are not siblings anymore, they get wrapped by `.scrollmagic-pin-spacer`